# YouTube Data API search not returning results for one specific YouTube Channel

Tags: php, curl, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I'm using the YouTube data API to bring in videos related to a specific channel using there Search: list function.

The function works fine and I have used it for months with no issues on many different channels.

Today thought, I found a channel that wouldn't send in its videos even though they were clearly public on the channel. 
The search query would send back a object that said "0 results returned"

Here is the function in question

```
//The url you wish to send the POST request to
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?'.'order='.$videoType.'&part=snippet'.'&channelId=' . $channelID.'&maxResults=' . $maxResults.'&key='.$API_key .$publishHolder.$nextPageTokenHolder;

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    //So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //execute post
    $videoList = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);
```

Like I said the problem is not the function or my code, as it works every were except for this one channel.

Does anyone know why there would be no results returned?

*A side not would be the channel is extremely small and only has 7 - 8 videos total, but I have also been successful with smaller channels in the past.*

EDIT

To answer some questions in the comments

- The channel id is UC8zmDqrUX0-b8blMHHV1XCA
- I will have to ask the client (Its his YouTube channel) to check and see if is something preventing it from working in his settings. 
  Is there a no-embed setting on youtube?
- And no the curl script is inside of a WordPress plugin I created. However its returning a object sent from YouTube that says "0 results returned", so even that is working. 
  YouTube is just simply "not finding anything".

Comment: Is it possible that the channel has prevented embedding? Or has some sort of privacy setting on? Does the API call work on its own as simply a curl, not embedded in your application?

Comment: What is the channelID?

Comment: Edited the question with more information ^